# Group cohomology: $\mathbb{Z}G$-maps from $G^{n+1}$ are the same as set maps from $G^n$

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

I'm learning about group cohomology from Knapp's book *Advanced Algebra*. Given a group $G$, and an abelian group $M$, he defines $F_n$ to be the $(n+1)$-fold product of $G$, endowed with a $G$-action by $g\cdot(g_0, g_1, \dotsc, g_n)= (gg_0, gg_1,  \dotsc, gg_n)$. Then he defines boundary maps $F_n \to F_{n-1}$ and applies $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(-, M)$ to get a cochain complex. He points out that $F_n$ is free as a $G$-module over the $(n+1)$-tuples with $1$ in the first entry. Further, $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(F_n, M)$ is isomorphic as an abelian group to $C^n(G, M)$, i.e. the abelian group of set maps from $G^n$ to $M$, via the isomorphism
$$\hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(F_n, M) \overset{\Phi}{\to} C^n(G,M)$$
$$\Phi(\varphi)(g_1, \dotsc, g_n) = \varphi(1, g_1, g_1g_2, \dotsc, g_1\dotsb g_n).$$

**My Question**: Why does he choose this isomorphism? I'm not seeing the point of the successive multiplication in later entries. It seems like 
$$\Phi(\varphi)(g_1, \dotsc, g_n) = \varphi(1, g_1, \dotsc, g_n)$$
would work. What am I missing?

Comment: see this math overflow question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6950/why-is-the-standard-definition-of-cocycle-the-one-that-always-comes-up

Comment: @hunter I see that that question raises the same issue I do; however, it is immediately raised to a level of generality I do not understand. I would appreciate if someone could help me through it.

Comment: Your isomorphism $\Phi$ would absolutely work. If you use it, you will come up with a different way to calculate $H^i(G, M)$, but it will be isomorphic to the way to calculate it in Knapp's book. However (as is sort of explained at the mathoverflow question ), the isomorphism $\Phi$ normalized as in Knapp ends up being the one that comes up in "practice" when one encounters $H^1$ in "nature." (Why this is so is a mystery to me, in spite of the good answers on that MO question.)